# Auto format / Clean up HTML Text

Tags: javascript, php, html, formatting

How to clean up repaire not html valide content text with php?

I got text like that:

```
<p>This is my list
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    end of my list
</p>
```

And after repair/cleaning it should looks like that:

```
<p>This is my list
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
    end of my list
</p>
```

I'm using CKEditor atm, but this is Build on JavaScript and I can't open every Content and save again. I need to run a PHP loop for it.

CKEditor is able to replace missing Tags and/or cleaning/repair content.

Please help.

Edit: I prefer a library to clean up this text, if exists.

Comment: try to look here http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php